# webViewDidFinishLoad not firing called working

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, swift, uiwebviewdelegate, webviewdidfinishload

(Swift, iOS8, Xcode6, iPhone/iPad)

`webViewDidFinishLoad` is not being called, is not firing, and is not working.

Yes, I have set the containing view controller as the delegate. I CTRL-mousedowned on the UIWebView, dragged up to the little yellow circle representing the view controller, and released. A right-click on the UIWebView object shows that the delegate is set.

Yes, I did implement `UIWebViewDelegate` in my class declaration, like so:

```
class Paragraph: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
```

Yes, I did restart Xcode, and test on both the simulator and an actual iPhone 4S.

The request looks like this:

```
@IBOutlet var paragraph : UIWebView = nil

var r = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cheddar", ofType: "htm")
var u = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: r)
paragraph.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: u))
```

The callback function looks like this:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad() {
    println("webViewDidFinishLoad")
}
```

Comment: `Method does not override any method from its superclass`

Comment: stupid question, but do you have `paragraph.delegate = self` in there before the `paragraph.loadRequest(…)` call?

Comment: I put it in there (although I don't see why it's needed if I wired the UIWebView delegate to the containing view controller in storyboard) but `webViewDidFinishLoad` is still not being called.

Comment: Thank you @Jiaaro, this is what I was missing!

Answer (score 4):

I got it. The callback was missing a parameter. For posterity:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {
```

Note the `webView: UIWebView!` parameter

In this case, perhaps even more important, is the way I found the bug. I created an entirely  new view controller, and pieced it back together, carefully checking at each step to make sure that I didn't miss anything.

When the Intellisense popup showed the function with the parameter, I saw my error.

NOTE: In Swift 2.2, the UIWebViewDelegate protocol specifies a different optionality: 
`webView: UIWebView`. 
`webView: UIWebView!` spawns a warning.